# `export` or `import` behaving different in webpack production than in development mode

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I'm trying to figure out why an app (Vuejs3, webpack 5, Babel 7) behaves differently in production than in development mode. For some reason, in production mode, the imports and exports are working differently (i.e. files aren't imported at all, i.e. their code isn't run during import).

This is the structure which works in development mode:

```
+- foo/
| +-- index.js
|     
|     export {default as Component} from './comp';
|     export {default as SomethingElse} from './comp2';
|
| +-- comp.vue
|
|     alert('hey there!');     
|     export default {...component here...}
|
+- main.js
   
   import './foo';
```

This works all fine in development mode, but not at all in production. I seems as if the code in `comp.vue` is never being executed and thus the component isn't imported/registered. I tried to use [re-exporting/aggregation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#re-exporting_aggregating) in `index.js` instead, but that didn't change anything.

If I change `main.js` to `import {Component} from './foo'` then everything works fine. However the `import 'file'` pattern is used so often that I would struggle to change it (and it works in development mode).

Another way to make this work is to set the source map to `eval-cheap-source-map` (instead of `source-map`) in production which is the same source map method used as in development. Conversely, if I change source map to `source-map` in development mode, the component is successfully loaded.

Which leads me to the conclusion that webpack is somehow handling export/import different in production that in develop (the source-map observation is just an observation, but worth noting). I'm a bit puzzled as to why this happens, so would like to appreciate any experience that you can share.

**Note**

This may be an issue with some of the production mode optimisation steps. Is there any way to disable them (all of them to see whether this is the general issue and then disable/re-enable parts of them to find the "culprit"?)

Comment: Yes, looks like the tree-shaking dead-code-elimination optimisation to me. Instead of disabling it, there's probably a way to annotate that `alert()` line not to be removed. Best practice would be not to rely on side effects from imported modules at all, but rather import a function (that does the `alert()`) and explicitly call that from `main`.

Comment: I can confirm that this is the issue. I changed `optimization: {minimize: true, minimizer: [new TerserPlugin(), new CssMinimizerPlugin()]}` to `optimization: {minimize: false}}` and all works fine (except for the huge file sizes ;-)).

Comment: Interesting comment re: "side effects". I actually make use of this pattern for setup code within the files quite a lot. It's also used to register components which is nice because it keeps the act of component registration within the component itself (it's only necessary to import the file). But I can see how this can trip up code optimisers. Can this part of the optimisation be configured (i.e. don't eliminate imports - only required code is imported, so that shouldn't be a problem with file size)?

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/ Not sure if there is a way to mark side effects (on the registration call) in the file itself

Comment: `optimization: {sideEffects: ...} ` and `optimization: {usedExports: ...}` for any combination of values don't have any effect. Only removing `new TerserPlugin()` from the `minimizer`s avoids this from happening. The way I read the side effects option is also that by default these imports aren't removed, so I wonder if is actually something else, as the tree shaking for this kind of case should be disabled by default (which makes sense as it's overly aggressive).

Comment: Ah, it might be the plugin not the native webpack tree-shaking

Comment: `TerserPlugin` delivers the "native webpack tree-shaking" as far as I can tell. If not specified (or excluded by not adding it to `minimizer`) `TerserPlugin` will be used by default (it's part of webpack 5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many unsuccessful attempts to fix this in the webpack configuration, I arrived at this configuration:

```
optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
      new TerserPlugin({
        terserOptions: {
          compress: {
            unused: false
          }
        }
      })
    ]
  },
```

> `unused` (default: true) -- drop unreferenced functions and variables (simple direct variable assignments do not count as references unless set to "keep_assign")

This seems to avoid side effect code from being culled when using re-exports. I'm yet to find out why the code was deemed side effect free though (which is not the default as far as I can tell).